# Can't import css file within React Web App

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I would like to import a pure css file into my react web app, so far I have tried this way:

In my index.tsx I have:

```
import * as React from "react"
import '../assets/styles.css';
```

In my webpack.config.js I have:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./src/index.tsx"
    ],

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css')
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"] },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, enforce: "pre", use: "source-map-loader" }
        ],
        loaders: [ {
            test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
            ]
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader') }
        ]
    }
};
```

Error:

> ERROR in ./src/assets/styles.css Module parse failed: Unexpected
>   character '@' (1:11) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this
>   file type.

Is it possible also that I can reference styles directly from index.html? If so how would I reference my styles.css? I already tried smth like this:

But this is not working, i dont know what is the path to the styles.css, thou in my directory I have it as src/assets/styles.css.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your rules:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
  ]
}
```